# Invoking worker threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote this class to ensure that anything done in any of my worker threads can be displayed on the GUI via events, but I ran into non-thread-safe problems.

This class should take an action or a function with one or no params, i.e. the event delegate.

Is this code actually thread-safe, and, how could it be improved upon (simplifying the 4 bodies into two or one)?

The class is defined as:

```
private class ThreadSafeCall
{

    public void Call(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
            if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                invokable.Invoke(action, null);
            }
            else
            {
                action();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public void Call(Action<object> action, object param)
    {
        try
        {
            ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
            if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                invokable.Invoke(action, new object[] { param });
            }
            else
            {
                action(param);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public object Call(Func<object> action)
    {
        try
        {
            ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
            if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                return invokable.Invoke(action, null);
            }
            else
            {
                return action();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }

    public object Call(Func<object, object> action, object param)
    {
        try
        {
            ISynchronizeInvoke invokable = action.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
            if (invokable != null && invokable.InvokeRequired == true)
            {
                return invokable.Invoke(action, new object[] { param });
            }
            else
            {
                return action(param);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

It is used:

```
(new ThreadSafeCall()).Call(() => { onCompleteHandle(); });
```

Comment: `catch (Exception)
            {

            }` is a bad, bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Your specific usage seems to be thread-safe. But it's relying on implementation details (about lambdas), which you shouldn't do. It's also **extremely** easy to get it wrong.

I believe the only way it will work is if you're closing over `this`, but not any other variables and that `this` is a type that properly implements `ISynchronizeInvoke` (like a WinForms form or control). This means that it won't work if:

- you're calling it from a `static` method
- you're only calling a `static` method from inside the lambda
- you're closing over some local variable or parameter
- you're calling it from another class

Because of that, I would never use code like this.

I think that you should just use `Invoke()` directly, something like:

```
Invoke(new Action(onCompleteHandle));
```

If you don't like that you need to specify the delegate type, you could write a couple of simple extension methods like:

```
public static void Invoke(this ISynchronizeInvoke target, Action action)
{
    target.Invoke(action, null);
}
```

and then use it like this (that `this` is required):

```
this.Invoke(onCompleteHandle);
```